# Selecting between two times

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

How can I Select all rows where start time is >= 8:00:00 and < 16:00:00?
[image: DB]

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_Schedule
WHERE HOUR(StartTime) >= '8:00:00'
  AND HOUR(EndTime) < '16:00:00'
```

However, it gave me the error:

> 'HOUR' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Mysql or SQL Server?? and what about `between`?

Comment: Seems to be a simple query. What problem did you encounter?

Comment: i used this query 
SELECT * FROM tbl_Schedule WHERE HOUR(StartTime) >= '8:00:00' AND HOUR(EndTime) < '16:00:00'
 and it gives me an error 
'HOUR' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: I am using SQL SERVER 2012

Comment: I have no idea what will be the query. I just saw that query in some related question that I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may depend on StartTime and EndTime columns type, but this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Schedule WHERE StartTime >= '8:00:00' AND EndTime < '16:00:00'
```